# Header is not redirecting to specific page after providing user name and password

Tags: php, redirect

I am using header statement to redirect my user to specific page after successful or un Successful login, but the header statement is not redirecting me to that specific page. and if i see the URL i can find (#) sign instead of the specific page

Though the same code is working on other server. I have read most of the questions and tried almost all the answer on Stackoverflow.com but all in vain. 
Here is my code:

```
if($_POST)
{
    ob_start();
    $office = $_POST["search_category"];
    $sub_category = $_POST["sub_category"];
    $password = md5($_POST["password"]);
    $query = "select * from contacts where officeid = $office and Posting = '$sub_category' and password = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Mistake in query');
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if ($count>=1)
     {
        $data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $_SESSION['user'] = $data['Posting']; 
        $_SESSION['semenu'] = $data['semenu'];
        $_SESSION['seid'] = $data['seid'];
        if ($_SESSION['semenu'] == 1 or $_SESSION['semenu'] == 2)
            header("location:contenrollment.php");
    else
        header("location:relogin.php");
        exit;
    ob_end_flush(); 
}?>
```

Instead of redirecting to any of the above two pages, I am redirected to a blank page and the blank page has the exact URL but only has (#) instead of file name. I have also checked the query, There is no mistake in it.

Comment: What is the data in your $_POST? It seems that there is no data being passed on the $_POST.

Comment: i have checked the data is posted properly in query, And query is giving output

Answer (score 0):

If your scripts located in root directory of site, try to use:

```
    header("Location: /contenrollment.php");
```

or

```
    header("Location: /relogin.php");
```

Comment: its not in root directory, Its at the same location with the login page, I mean both the pages are at the same place